# Visual studio unit tests showing as inconclusive when more than 9 are added to project

Tags: macos, visual-studio

When attempting to run my unit tests I've been having some strange behaviour, previously I've been able to run my tests without adding another one as I was getting a similar error but now I can't run any, I'm getting this error when running;

```
Unable to write data to the transport connection: The socket has been shut down.
Stack trace:
  at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 size) [0x000c3] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/System/net/System/Net/Sockets/NetworkStream.cs:602 
  at System.IO.Stream.WriteByte (System.Byte value) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/io/stream.cs:770 
  at System.IO.BinaryWriter.Write (System.Byte value) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/io/binarywriter.cs:152 
  at System.IO.BinaryWriter.Write7BitEncodedInt (System.Int32 value) [0x00004] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/io/binarywriter.cs:427 
  at System.IO.BinaryWriter.Write (System.String value) [0x0001b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/io/binarywriter.cs:370 
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.SocketCommunicationManager.WriteAndFlushToChannel (System.String rawMessage) [0x0001b] in <b490783f77944638be7b669258bc82b9>:0 
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.SocketCommunicationManager.SendMessage (System.String messageType, System.Object payload) [0x0000e] in <b490783f77944638be7b669258bc82b9>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.DotNetCore.UnitTesting.DotNetCoreTestPlatformAdapter.GetProcessStartInfo (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] testAssemblies) [0x00019] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/b604c37c/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.DotNetCore/MonoDevelop.DotNetCore.UnitTesting/DotNetCoreTestPlatformAdapter.cs:450 
  at MonoDevelop.DotNetCore.UnitTesting.DotNetCoreTestPlatformAdapter.DebugTests (MonoDevelop.UnitTesting.TestContext testContext, MonoDevelop.DotNetCore.UnitTesting.IDotNetCoreTestProvider testProvider, System.String testAssemblyPath) [0x0002b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/b604c37c/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.DotNetCore/MonoDevelop.DotNetCore.UnitTesting/DotNetCoreTestPlatformAdapter.cs:417
```

Sorry for the massive blob of copy and pasted code. I've tried multiple solutions such as clean rebuild, reloading the project, moving the tests into different projects, different classes etc and nothing has solved this issue. The only thing I could think about would be to clear the temporary files but I can't find any information online on which file's I'd need to clear on Mac.

EDIT 1: 
This only appears to be happening when I have anymore than 9 tests, I've reinstalled visual studio, done dotnet restore on the project which is all I can find on google, I believe the error message above was just an issue after the real one which I think is;

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument argument)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.ContainsKey(TKey key)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.Parallel.ParallelProxyExecutionManager.StartTestRun(TestRunCriteria testRunCriteria, ITestRunEventsHandler eventHandler)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Client.Execution.TestRunRequest.ExecuteAsync()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommandLine.TestPlatformHelpers.TestRequestManager.RunTests(TestRunCriteria testRunCriteria, ITestRunEventsRegistrar testRunEventsRegistrar, ProtocolConfig protocolConfig)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommandLine.TestPlatformHelpers.TestRequestManager.RunTests(TestRunRequestPayload testRunRequestPayload, ITestHostLauncher testHostLauncher, ITestRunEventsRegistrar testRunEventsRegistrar, ProtocolConfig protocolConfig)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Client.DesignMode.DesignModeClient.<>c__DisplayClass18_0.<StartTestRun>b__0()
```

This error is gotten when debugging one of the failed tests which show as: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GO8XB.jpg.

EDIT 2: This is also happening when I've created a new XUnit test project. As you can see in this image of 9 tests, they are discovered and ran fine: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBiIO.jpg. But once adding the tenth test I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8ixG.jpg. And when running these tests the output window shows: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiFfv.jpg.

EDIT 3: After some more digging I found some information about this which has lead me to a solution. The issue is with .NET core project unit tests having a bug which limits them to 9, this is fixed in version 7.3 of Visual Studio which isn't the current version. After changing my updates to Alpha versions I've downloaded 7.3 and fixed my issues; more information on this can be found  here https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/90031/test-pad-breaks-after-exceeding-9-test-methods-xun.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my edit mentinons - After some more digging I found some information about this which has lead me to a solution. The issue is with .NET core project unit tests having a bug which limits them to 9, this is fixed in version 7.3 of Visual Studio which isn't the current version. After changing my updates to Alpha versions I've downloaded 7.3 and fixed my issues; more information on this can be found here https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/90031/test-pad-breaks-after-exceeding-9-test-methods-xun.html.